# If function and its derivative are zero at a point, then is the second and third derivative also zero [fourth order differential]?

Tags: derivatives

The example I am working on is that of a string attached and deflected by a force along its length. Edit: There is something supporting it in the middle.
We can say that the deflection, $f(x)$, must be zero at the frontier $f(0)=f(L)=0$ along with its derivative $\frac{\partial f(0)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(L)}{\partial x} = 0$

Does the second and third derivative also evaluate zero at $x=0$ and $x=L$, considering that it is a fourth order differential equation?

Edit: the deflection can be expressed as $\frac{\partial^4 f(x)}{\partial x^4} = c P(x)$ with $P(x)$ being the pressure applied

Comment: $f(x)=x^2(x-L)^2$ is an obvious counterexample.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: But doesn't OP require zero first derivatives at two points also? Wouldn't we need something like $\cos \frac{2\pi x}{L} - 1$ or something? ETA: OBE.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, it is a fourth order differential equation.

Comment: @BrianTung I updated the comment with an example fulfilling that constraints.

Comment: @Mooder Th OP updated the question... Always nice to shoot at a moving target!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes I saw that.